# Fully block asynchronous calls in nodejs like Meteor._wrapAsync

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm

I have the following code in Meteor (nodejs framework)

```
dbAllSync = Meteor._wrapAsync(db.all.bind(db))
rows = dbAllSync(query)
```

With the above code I am able to fully block the db call i.e. the code execution will only continue to the line after when the query results have been fetched.

How can I achieve the same full block code execution in nodejs without using Meteor._wrapAsync?

P.s. - I have tried 'sync' and 'synchronise' node packages. It didn't server my purpose. They don't have full-block code execution but non-blocking code execution.

Also, I know full-block is against the nodejs principle. But I have some requirements to implement and for that I want nodejs to be full-block at some points in code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood, `Meteor.wrapAsync` is a wrapper around the `fibers/future` library.

https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers

The fibers mechanism doesn't full-block the node event loop, the whole process kepts executing stuff in a non-blocking asynchronous way, it just appears synchronous to the developer.

This is very different from the `fs` functions like `writeSync` that are truly blocking the process.

EDIT : adding some boilerplate code :

```
var Future=require("fibers/future");

var future=new Future();
api.someAsyncFunc(params,future.resolver());
future.wait();
```

You can dig in the docs of the node-fibers npm module to find more about nice wrapping functionalities like `Future.wrap`.

https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers#futures